# react-native-share method shareSingle opening Play Store in Android 11

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play, react-native-share

When I use the following method it's should open the Whatsapp for share the message, but it open the Google Play in the page of the Whatsapp...

```
Share.shareSingle({
  title: 'Title Test',
  message: 'Message Test',
  social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

In then console return: `{"message": null, "success": true}`

I'm using...
React Native: 0.64.0
React Native Share: 6.2.3
Android 11

When I use the example of the React Native Share it's work success, but I don't understand why don't work in my application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem!

In the Android 11 some information about other apps are "blocked", using the method `Share.isPackageInstalled` I realized that return not installed, then to "unblock" this we need use `<queries>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for more details read [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility). 
[Implement queries in AndroidManifest](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

Comment: can u please share code for it. like this link https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/1103#issuecomment-928231184

Comment: I can't share whole the code because the owner is a private enterprise, but you can read the docs in [here](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/install#adding-queries-for-the-android-necessary-for-sdk--30) and your code should be like:  

<queries>  
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" /> <!-- WhatsApp package ID -->  
</queries>